# Spring bean comma separating values, but I want to overwrite

Tags: html, spring, jsp, csv, path

Alright, so I'm pretty new to Spring, but I was asked to resolve a bug. So in our application, we have a page that queries a database based on an id. However, not all entries are unique to the id. The id and date pair, on the other hand, do define unique entries.

So this page takes in an id. If there is only a single entry related to this id, everything works fine. However, if there are multiple entries, the page displays a radio button selection of the various dates that pertain to that id. We use something like:

> < form:radiobutton id="loadDate" path="loadDate" value="${date}" label="${date}" />

Later on the same page, we want to display the data for that option. As part of it, we display the date of that selection:

> < form:input id="aiLoadDate" path="loadDate" maxlength="22" size="22" class="readonly" readonly="true"/>

The problem is that when this happens, the variable (or bean? I'm not quite sure about Spring yet..) loadDate (a string) ends up being the same date twice, seperated with a comma. I'm guessing the problem here is the "path="loadDate"" that is common to both lines.

Instead of appending the date to the already existing one like a csv, I'd like it to overwrite the current entry intead. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is not the direct cause of your problem.  When the elements of an HTML form are submitted, each element will appear in the request as a name=value pair.  If two or more elements in the form have the same name (not id, name attribute) then those elements appear in the request as name=value,value (with one value per element with a duplicated name).

Option 1: stop using an input as a display element.  Just display the date in a span (or div or paragraph or what ever).  If you want the look of an input box (border, etc.) use CSS to create a class that has the look you want and attach the class to the span (or div or paragraph, etc) in which you display the date.

Option2: continue using an input as a display element.  Disabled input elements are not added to the request when the form is submitted.  in the form:imput set disabled="true".

Comment: Thanks so much! Option2 worked for me. 

The only drawback is that the text appears grey'd out, so I'm looking for a solution to this currently. Probably a quick style fix.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. It seems that while disabling the input field works for multiple entries, it breaks it for single entries. Aparently, that form:input is where the single entries get their date information from